# C++ Compilation problems on OS X after Mavericks upgrade

Tags: c++, macos, linker, g++, clang

The code I am working on was compiling fine before the upgrade but now when I come to link all of my files together using either:

g++ {List of *.o files} Executable -l...

or the same thing with clang as my compiler I get an error for every function call from a linked function along the lines of:

```
"fastjet::sorted_by_pt(std::__1::vector<fastjet::PseudoJet, std::__1::allocator<fastjet::PseudoJet> > const&)", referenced from:
  _main in ZJetGen.o
  CZMultijet::weight() in ZJets.o
...

"std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
...
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Thanks in advance
Jack

Comment: 'Along the lines of' is not good enough. Post the exact, full, error that you are getting. Even better: write a (small!) code snippet that reproduces the error. Often just by doing this you will find the mistake yourself, and if not it will give us (hopefully) enough information to help.

Comment: looks like the libc++ library has been moved and you get the wrong one.

Comment: @thelamb, the above is a definition of the problem.  The only difference between what I posted and the error message is one is a few hundred lines longer.

Comment: @Walter, Thanks - I will look in to whether Apple have moved its location.  If as you suspect they have moved it how might I go about fixing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because header file got deleted after the update the Mavericks, so you need to install them, here are the steps:

1. Install or update to the new 5.0.1 XCode
2. Install Command Line Tools In OSX 10.9 Mavericks, by typing the following command in a terminal window, then click on install:
   ***xcode-select --install***

Now it should work fine

Comment: Cheers @chekkal, I have Xcode 5.0.1 but that doesnt help - and when I try xcode-select --install I get an error that the package is not available?

Comment: Hi @Jack, try installing command line tools  by opening XCode, click on XCode menu Item -> Open Developer Tools -> More Developer tools now you'll be directed to apple site from there you can download command line tools (OSx Mavericks)